# How can I implement new line in a column (DataTables)

Tags: datatables

I have an SQL query that grabs some data (*language* column in *dbtable* table). The query uses GROUP_CONCAT, so one cell has several results, e.g.

```
"Ajax, jQuery, HTML, CSS".
```

What I want to do is to show the result in new lines, like:

```
"Ajax
jQuery
HTML
CSS"
```

How can I do that?

I tried to make it by changing *"columns": [{ "data": "id" }, { "data": "languages" }*... but it didn't work.

I also tried to fix it by adding "< br >" in query as a Separator, but didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function for the column like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        null,
        null,
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4644q44s/).

Hope that helps and that I've understood your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**To implement new line in a column for DataTables**

Assume that there are 7 columns in a row and the 4th column has the data

```
"Ajax, jQuery, HTML, CSS"
```

so the 3 columns before and 3 columns after has to be made null in the code

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        null, null, null,
        {   
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
            }
        },
        null, null, null
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`@annoyingmouse` answer is perfect taking into account the question description!

Just an extra answer following "strictly" the question (as it is) which says:

> How can I implement new line in a column (DataTables)

You have just to add a `wrap` class on the `<table>` tag. Tada! Each column text will be wrapped when reaching its predefined width.