# New lines not being perserved via ajax get bound via json but is in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I am using Jquery on my Data Table but its not preserving the new lines or carriage returns, but the values are fine in the database and when I copy them into SSMS it displays them correctly in its text editor.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = @ViewBag.CaseId;

    $("#audTrailTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "/MISObjects/GetAuditTrailData/" + id,
            type: "get",
            database: "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "createdDate" },
            { "data": "createdBy" },
            { "data": "action" }
        ],
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false // for disable multiple column at once
    })
});
</script>
```

My Html

```
<table id="audTrailTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

My Method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>>> GetAuditTrailData(int? id) {
    int? resulCaseId = id;
    var auditTrailsHistory = _context.MisAuditTrail.Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false && w.MISObjectId == resulCaseId).ToList();
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditTrailsHistory);

    DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>> data = new DataTableWrapper<List<MISAuditTrail>>() {
        data = auditTrailsHistory
    };

    return data;
}
```

Comment: This has been answered before in a very similar question. See '[How can I implement new line in a column in datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791577/how-can-i-implement-new-line-in-a-column-datatables)'

Comment: He is splitting is columns its not the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display  the new lines or carriage returns of the data in the datatable, we need to add the **`render`** method to **determine whether the newline or carriage return character is included when binding the columns in datatable js function**.

If it does, add `<br/>` in the corresponding position to ensure that the the line wrapping effect is displayed in the table.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = @ViewBag.CaseId;
    $("#audTrailTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "/MISObjects/GetAuditTrailData/" + id,
            type: "get",
            database: "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "createdDate" },
            { "data": "createdBy" },
            {
                        "data": "action",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            if (type === "sort" || type === "type") {
                                return data;
                            }
                            var match = /\r|\n/.exec(data);
                            String.prototype.splice = function (idx, rem, str) {
                                 return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
                            };
                            if (match) {
                                data = data.splice(match.index, 0, "<br />");
                            }
                            return data;
                        }
                    },
        ],
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false // for disable multiple column at once
    })
});
</script>
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: wow all that for just a br seems over kill mabe time to switch to blazor

Comment: thank u will give it a try I no it will work with your abilities though.